# Http post request with DNA EXCEL C#

Tags: http

I am making addin in excel to get data from website and present it to excel . I use DNA Excel in C# and Xnet library . it can operate in console app but when i write it in to class library project , it can not run

this is my code

namespace ClassLibrary4
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static Object ht (string a)
        {

```
        var http = new HttpRequest();
        var reqParams = new RequestParams();
        reqParams["client_id"] = "aef5dcf3-cd31-46d0-9f56-b1738cd5078d";
        reqParams["client_secret"] = "933D8E89C8058B058A84A68C19C81322BD060710";
        reqParams["grant_type"] = "client_credentials";
        reqParams["scopes"] = "PublicApi.Access";
        string token = http.Post("https://id.kiotviet.vn/connect/token", reqParams).ToString();

        return token;

    }
}
```

}

and this is a code in console app ( that can operate )
using System;
using xNet;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

```
        var http = new HttpRequest();
        var reqParams = new RequestParams();
        reqParams["client_id"] = "aef5dcf3-cd31-46d0-9f56-b1738cd5078d";
        reqParams["client_secret"] = "933D8E89C8058B058A84A68C19C81322BD060710";
        reqParams["grant_type"] = "client_credentials";
        reqParams["scopes"] = "PublicApi.Access";
        string token = http.Post("https://id.kiotviet.vn/connect/token", reqParams).ToString();
       Console.WriteLine(token);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHbZm.png)

Comment: What does it actually do to fail?
re you including the class library in another project correctly?

Comment: i was edit question with the correct code in console app and when i run the code in excel . That return results !VALUE . i was attach with the picture

Comment: Sorry, have you stepped through the program, does token exist once the writeline is hit? Should this be a https request instead of http?